# I want to use "if and elif" Inside the Send_mail function in Django

Tags: python, django

What I want to achieve is
I want to use "if and elif" Inside the Send_mail function in Django
but an error occurs and I don't know how to fix it...

Error message

```
potential arugment cannot appear after keyword aurgument
```

[image]

```
        send_mail(
            subject='New message', 
            message='Access to http://localhost:3000/messagerooms', 
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, 
            if inquiry_user == self.request.user:
                recipient_list = post.user.email
            elif post.user == self.request.user:
                recipient_list = inquiry_user.email
            )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put an `if` suite inside a call expression. You could use a conditional operator (`x if y else z`), but it's easier to use just a regular `if`:

```
if inquiry_user == self.request.user:
    recipient_list = [post.user.email]
elif post.user == self.request.user:
    recipient_list = [inquiry_user.email]
else:
    raise ValueError("Can't determine recipient")


send_mail(
    subject="New message",
    message="Access to http://localhost:3000/messagerooms",
    from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    recipient_list=recipient_list,
)
```